# How to set Input Date from var value (3/10/2020) in jquery?

Tags: jquery, date, datetime, input, format

i am trying to set date from var  has value "3/10/2020" my iput tag is like,

```
var dt = (value.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + value.getDate() + "/" + value.getFullYear();

dt = 3/10/2020
```

setting value in input date like,

```
 <input type="date" id="DecDate" name="birthday">
$('#DecDate').val(dt);
```

But it is not showing date in input not giving any error

Hopes for your suggestions.

Comment: If you're going to use a string it needs to be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format (note other formats will not work, eg `YY-M-D`). Alternatively, use the [`valueAsDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) property

Comment: How will i use it in my code ?\

Comment: There's a full example in the duplicate